# org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers

Tags: soap, jaxb, spring-integration, soap-client

I am new to soap and spring integration and I am trying to call an soap service using spring-integration, but I am getting the exception saying "Dispatcher has no subscribers". I have pasted my code below. Please help me out where I am going wrong.

soapcall-config.xml

```
<int:gateway id="ws" service-interface="com.sa.WsGateway"
    default-request-channel="inputChannel" />

<ws:outbound-gateway request-channel="inputChannel"
    uri="http://localhost:8080/spring-webservices-sample/endpoints" />

<int:service-activator ref="dispMess" method="display"
    input-channel="inputChannel"></int:service-activator>
```

Runner.java

```
Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("soapcall-config.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  
    WsGateway wsGateway=factory.getBean("ws", WsGateway.class);
    AccountDetailsRequest accountDetailsRequest=new AccountDetailsRequest();
    accountDetailsRequest.setAccountNumber("12345");
    wsGateway.callWS(accountDetailsRequest);
```

DispMess.java

```
public class DispMess {
    public void display(AccountDetailsResponse res){
    System.out.println(res.getAccountDetails());
}
```

}

WsGateway.java

```
public interface WsGateway {
    public void callWS(AccountDetailsRequest request);
```

}

Even I tried changing the uri of the outbound gateway to the wsdl path of webservice. But still the error exists.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue: You should start application, but `XmlBeanFactory` doesn't do that for you.

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is for your case.

Take a look to the [Spring Integration Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples).

Another issue: you have two subscribes for the `inputChannel`. By default `DirectChannel` uses `round-robin` dispatching strategy. Hence the first message is sent to the first subscriber, the second - to the second, and so on.